# Select Filtering JArray

Tags: c#

I have a JArray as follow:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 5447,
    "attributes": {
    "alarm": "Mode1"
   },
  "deviceId": 28
 },
 {
   "id": 5448,
   "attributes": {
   "alarm": "Mode1"
  },
  "deviceId": 28
  },
   {
     "id": 5449,
     "attributes": {
     "alarm": "Mode2"
   },
   "deviceId": 28
  }
]
```

how to filter by `["attributes"]["alarm"] == "Mode1"` ?

I tried:

```
JArray _new_ja = __ja_alarm.Where(p => p["attributes"]["alarm"].ToString() == "Mode1");
```

it returns null?

Comment: Step 1 in every JSON problem - convert it to C# classes _first_. https://app.quicktype.io?share=PZfKI97ZUnMm1SM9emmS

Answer (score 1):

You could just deserialize it

**Given**

```
public class Attributes    {
   public string alarm { get; set; } 
}

public class Model    {
   public int id { get; set; } 
   public Attributes attributes { get; set; } 
   public int deviceId { get; set; } 
}
```

**Usage**

```
var model = JsonConvert
    .DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(input)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.attributes.alarm == "Mode1");
```

**Or**

```
var result = JArray
    .Parse(input)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => (string) x["attributes"]["alarm"] == "Mode1")
    .ToObject<Model>();
```

Use `Where` instead of  `FirstOrDefault` If you want a list of matches